# PHP Site not working after renaming/adding new page

Tags: php

On my site, I had an `index.php` with a navbar. Then, I needed to add another page, called `second.php`, and updated my navbar code accordingly (I have a `nav.html` file for the navbar, so that I can use JS to load it onto each page of the site). I also added the navbar code to the `second.php`. However, when I opened `index.php`, the link to `second.php` didn't appear.

I tried restarting my computer, restarting my MAMP server, reopening my code editor, reopening the browser, but nothing worked. Then, I tried renaming my files (for both the purpose of testing and because I needed better file names) and updated all instances of the name of the files accordingly. But then this appeared:

[image]

followed by a list of the files in my directory. In particular, the site wasn't displaying. Could someone please explain what's happening and how I can fix it?

`nav.html`:

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <h1 class="logo-text"><a href="home.php">Welcome!</a></h1>
        </div>
        <i class="fa fa-bars menu-toggle"></i>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</body>
```

`home.php` (formerly `second.php`):

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kalam&family=Pangolin&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Welcome Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('.placeholder').load("nav.html");
        });
    </script>    

    hello world


    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

`about.php` (formerly `index.html`) is basically the same as `home.php` except it has a couple of paragraph tags.

Comment: I believe what's happening with the `Index of /` text is that the current URL isn't pointing to an existing file on your server and you don't have a 404 page configured. You didn't need to specifically go to `localhost/index.php` initially because `index` is a common "home" page as defined in your server settings (index.php, index.html, etc are all common default configurations). Please edit your question and share your PHP code in `index.php`, `nav.html`, `second.php` so we can help you debug your code further.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what the issue still is. What URL are you trying to load and what's appearing on that page? I'm guessing if you go to http://localhost/home.php your home page should load, right? Also you can replace your placeholder div and script with `<?php include "./nav.html"; ?>` to include `nav.html` instead of doing it asynchronously via JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear on what isn't working at this point, so I might as well share a working example I have locally. I'm accessing my site at `http://localhost/so/`, and going to that URL will load any `index` page I have. I have 3 files inside the `/so` directory:

nav.html (I removed your `<body>` tags because those already exist in the other files):

```
<header>
    <div class="logo">
        <h1 class="logo-text"><a href="home.php">Welcome!</a></h1>
    </div>
    <i class="fa fa-bars menu-toggle"></i>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

home.php (accessible at localhost/so/home.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kalam&family=Pangolin&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Welcome Home</title>
</head>
<body>
   <?php include "./nav.html"; ?>

    hello world home

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: localhost/so/home.php]

about.php (accessible at localhost/so/about.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kalam&family=Pangolin&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Welcome About</title>
</head>
<body>
   <?php include "./nav.html"; ?>

    hello world about

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: localhost/so/about.php]

If I rename `home.php` to `index.php` then I can go to either `localhost/so/` or `localhost/so/index.php` to access that file.

[image: localhost/so/index.php]

Slightly related: you shouldn't necessarily use `time()` as your CSS cache busting variable because it won't cache at all then. You should use a variable that you manually adjust the value of (i.e. `$css_cache_bust = "2020061001";`) like `href="css/style.css?v=<?= $css_cache_bust; ?>"` so you can incrementally adjust this *as needed*.

Comment: Wow, for some reason my main issue was already fixed when I opened it today! The Home and About tabs are both present now. I think you've solved the other issue of the ```index.php``` and the site not working on startup, so thanks for that!